# Adjusting event.labels in addEventLines in the new xts (old xtsExtra)

Tags: r, xts

A very basic question, I'm afraid, but I'm struggling to understand what controls I have over event.labels in the new xts(old xtsExtra). I would like to:

1. resize the text of these labels
2. adjust the offset (distance) between the text and the lines themselves
3. ideally have the option to have the text inside a legend at the side of the chart

Some basic code:

```
library(quantmod)
library(xts)

getSymbols('F',src='yahoo')
F.Close <- F[,4]
zoo.F <- as.zoo(F.Close)
xF <- as.xts(zoo.F)

plot.xts(xF)
addEventLines(event.dates="2013-01-05",event.labels = "Motor Show",
date.format="%Y-%m-%d",main="",on=1,lty=1,lwd=3,col="red")
```

Also if anyone can point me in the direction of some primers on this functionality I'd be grateful. Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Some of the arguments to control the labels were hardcoded in the `addEventLines()` function which is why you weren't able to resize the text or adjust the offset of the labels. We removed the hardcoded values for `offset`, `pos`, and `srt` and now pass `...` through to the call to `text` in `addEventLines()` which draws the labels.

See http://joshuaulrich.github.io/xts/plotting_basics.html for examples of adding event lines as well as adding a legend to address your third point.

Comment: I tried the following code, but am still struggling to get control of offset, pos, srt and cex                                                                         addEventLines(c("2007-03-20","2013-01-05"), c("foo", "bar"), on=1,
              offset=1.8, pos=2, srt=90, cex=4, lwd=3,col=c("red","blue"))

Comment: I redownloaded xts via install.packages("xts", repos="http://R-Forge.R-project.org")  but to no avail

Comment: @RichS: re-installing from R-Forge won't help.  Development has [moved to GitHub](https://github.com/joshuaulrich/xts).

Comment: How do I change the position of the labels on the Y-axis?